# Sonarqube analysis -Team Foundation Server

Tags: c#, sonarqube

In Team foundation server 2015, a build definition is created and the following tasks are done sequentially.
1.Sonarqube Begin analysis
2.MSBuild task -a .NET C# application 
3.Sonarqube end task .

The error is reported in the 3rd step as it fails but MSbuild task succeeds.

I even tried to execute these steps in the command prompt and still the same error occurs.

Comment: Could you attach the error log?

Comment: What are the versions of the TFS SonarQube components?

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks ,,,could not upload the file currently..Sonarqube version 6.5 , Failed to find the code coverage command line tool. Possible cause: Visual Studio is not installed, or the installed version does not support code coverage.
Errors:
1. The project has not been built - the end step was called right after the begin step, without a build step in between.
2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 12.0 upwards are supported
3. The build step has been launched from a different working folder.

Comment: sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778

Comment: Any suggestions on this yet..